# WP_Query get other table column values

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to fetch another table column by `WP_Query` but it does not work.

**Note**: I can easily do this by `$wpdb->get_results( 'custom_sql' )` but I want to do it by `WP_Query`

**My code**

```php
function join_my_query( $join, $wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $wp_query->get( 'custom_logic' ) === true ) {
        $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as pm ON $wpdb->posts.ID = pm.post_id ";
    }

    return $join;
}

add_filter( 'posts_join', 'join_my_query', 10, 2 );
    

$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'custom_logic' => true,
        'post_type'    => 'post',
    )
);
```

It's giving me SQL like below, which does not select any column from the joined table!

**Generated SQL**

```sql
SELECT
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID
FROM
  wp_posts
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as pm ON wp_posts.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE
  1 = 1
  AND (
    (
      wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
      AND (
        wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
        OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future'
        OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft'
        OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending'
      )
    )
  )
ORDER BY
  wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT
  0, 10
```

It does not select any column from my joined table. I have use `var_dump($query->posts[0])` which return a `WP_Post` object and it has no column from my joined table. How I can get columns from my joined table with `WP_Query` like below

**My Goal**

```php
$post = $query->posts[0];
$post->meta_key; // from my joined table, not work
$post->pm->meta_key; // pm is alias used in join, still not work
```

Comment: Have you tried to add db table prefix before the table name postmeta?

Comment: @KrunalBhimajiyani `$wpdb->postmeta` will add db table prefix by default. You can see SQL part which generated by `WP_Query`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your expected result, the `posts_join` filter is not required. You can do this with the `posts_clauses` filter easily!

```php
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'modify_post_clauses_callback' , 10, 2 );

function modify_post_clauses_callback( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
    if ( $wp_query->get( 'custom_logic' ) === true ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $clauses['fields']  = $clauses['fields'] . ', pm.meta_key';
        $clauses['join']    = "LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} as pm ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = pm.post_id";
    }

    return $clauses;
}

$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'custom_logic' => true,
        'post_type'    => 'post',
    )
);

$post = $query->posts[0];
$post->meta_key;
```